How to manage npm packages in my repository
I wanted to make a discord bot so I used npm for the first time, I created a package file and installed discord.js but now I have 3000 files that i could sync in my repository, it seems like a stupid thing to do, what should I do?
I guess i should put some files into .gitignore but which ones shoud be left into the repo?

The node_modules folder is automatically generated when you use npm i or npm install, and this can get quite large. It's best to add the node_modues folder to your .gitignore.
You could maybe use this .gitignore file: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore

You can always copy this block, it covers up, i guess, anything. create a .gitignore file inside your repo and paste the block there.
That way the npm packages won't sync in your repository.
Also if someone want's to fork your repo , all he/she/it has to do is an "npm i" in the terminal while cd'd in the right folder and everything's going to be up and running.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
